# Return top N rows per group in MySQL, but efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a pretty simple table in MySQL 5.7.30, which I boiled down to the three columns below. I'm trying to determine top N elements per group for some groups (`WHERE groupable IN (3, 4, 5)`). But I cannot do it efficiently even for a single group (see `WHERE groupable = 3` below).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    groupable BIGINT NOT NULL,
    orderable BIGINT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX test_index_1 (groupable, orderable),
    UNIQUE INDEX test_index_2 (orderable, groupable),
    INDEX test_index_3 (orderable),
    INDEX test_index_4 (groupable)
);
INSERT INTO test(groupable, orderable) VALUES
    (1, 100), (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103), (1, 104), (1, 105), (1, 106), (1, 107),
    (2, 200), (2, 201), (2, 202), (2, 203), (2, 204), (2, 205), (2, 206), (2, 207),
    (3, 300), (3, 301), (3, 302), (3, 303), (3, 304), (3, 305), (3, 306), (3, 307),
    (4, 400);


EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM test
WHERE groupable = 3
ORDER BY orderable LIMIT 2;
```

The final `EXPLAIN` returns the `rows` value of 8. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows), "*the rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.*" I was hoping that having a `(groupable, orderable)` index would alleviate the need to examine every row with `groupable = 3` and allow the engine to access the largest ones directly. Is that not the case? Is there a way around that?

I see people ask this question all the time, but all the answers I've seen so far seem to have the same downside: examining every row per group. Or for those that don't have a `WHERE/IN` clause, examining the whole table.

Thanks for your help!

*Note*: while this example is small, I've reproduced the same on a table with thousands of groupables and hundreds of rows for each groupable.

*Note* #2: I've added extra indexes just in case, to make sure I'm not missing some hidden optimisation.

Comment: For such a small sample table a table scan is faster than using indexes...

Comment: For general optimizations, the individual indexes would be redundant as the [first column(s) defined in the composite index are accessible by the engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), similar to the optimizations seen for `LIKE 'first_column(s) %'` vs `LIKE '% last_column'`. So only `UNIQUE INDEX test_index_1 (groupable, orderable), INDEX test_index_2 orderable` should be needed.

Comment: I'm not understanding the perception of inefficiency. Are you expecting `rows: 2`? There are in-fact 8 rows that contain `groupable=3` that are then ordered and limited to 2 results, which is the desired effect, as MySQL finds the rows with the specified criteria. Not using an INDEX would cause `rows: 25, extra: using filesort` in the EXPLAIN instead of just `rows: 8, extra: using index`.  Optimizing further would require using/knowing the primary key indexes of the groupable values.

Comment: Note: the point of shadow's comment is that you Can Not infer performance / behavior from such a small sample. All that data well be read into memory from a single page on the disk. Looking at indexes, etc, would involve reading additional pages, so the optimiser won't bother. Write a script to generate a larger test data set, with a representative number of rows, a representative distribution of keys, and inserted in a representative order (to cause representative index fragmentation, etc). THEN run Explain.

Comment: @Shadow That's why I mentioned in the end that the result is the same if there are 500 rows to inspect, interspersed throughout a 100000-row table.

Comment: @WillB. I don't know how MySQL indexes are implemented, but yes, I was hoping that in a composite index it would be able to find the head (or tail) or a particular subsequence (e.g. (3, 0) to (4, 0)) and then simply use the first (or last) two rows it encounters. Perhaps they decided this use-case is too niche to bother with, but it's definitely not impossible to do.

Comment: @NikitaRybak In the singular criteria EXPLAIN query, I believe you are thinking of rows too literally, as opposed to taking into account the rows+filtered+extra to determine the estimated efficiency. Emphasis on estimated. Is the root issue you are having retrieving the tuples of N rows per group? Using `MIN/MAX` and eval of `<` or `>` to filter the desired `ID` is another approach to get the first/last tuples to further optimize based on ID, but would need to see your desired results for the tuples, since it is not clear if you want 2 per group or just 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composite index that includes the grouping and ordering column will fully cover this query. Additionally, mysql will stop reading the index as soon as it finds the number of results specified in the LIMIT.

In this way, the query will not examine all the rows when it actually runs. The EXPLAIN clause is an approximation and does not include this short-circuit LIMIT optimization in its estimation for ROWS examined.

From the docs...
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

> MySQL stops sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html

> Using index -
> The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.

Comment: That's exactly it! In the end, I found that _"FLUSH STATUS; <DO_SQL_HERE>; SHOW SESSION STATUS where Variable_name LIKE 'Handler%';"_ displays a more accurate account of what the query involves.

Comment: Also, this addresses the same question directly https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,597352,597431#msg-597431

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have a dimension table, where the groupable id is unique?

Then, I'd use a join and a correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT
  dim.id,
  fact.*
FROM
  dim_groupable    AS dim
LEFT JOIN
  fact_groupable   AS fact
    ON fact.id IN (
      SELECT id
        FROM fact_groupable
       WHERE groupable = dim.id
    ORDER BY orderable
       LIMIT 2
    )
```

Then make the index cover `groupable, orderable, id`, so that the correlated sub-query can be anserwed with the index alone.

If you don't have a dimension table just use `(SELECT DISTINCT groupable AS id FROM fact_groupable) AS dim`. But, you really should have a dimension table.

Comment: Yes, groupable is a primary key in another table. When I run this though, I get "*This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'*", even if I add explicit "groupable = 3".

Comment: And beyond that, it seems surprising that JOIN is the thing that would make it use the index, even though the main table already has an index on groupable.

Comment: @NikitaRybak - My trite response would then be to use MySQL 8 and `ROW_NUMBER()` :(  I've had a tinker with your smaller example, and a possibility is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=58359c42bab6df8190fc27723bab55c9

Comment: Thanks for looking! And that's not a trite response, it's very valid and I cannot wait till our platform folks can actually make that happen :)